# Extract/Get PnP Provisioning Template with tokens

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, pnp-powershell, pnp

Is there a way of getting the pnp provisioning template xml of a site with the [tokens](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/ProvisioningEngineTokens.md) instead of the actual values??

I'm always facing this whenever we have multiple environments and I just have to "copy" the structure from one to another environment and on the site there is data or navigation links pointing to the site urls but I couldn't find a way of "tokenize" them by default. Currently what I do is, I extract the template, read it (Read-PnPProvisioningTemplate) find the site urls as string change them to the respective token and save the "tokenized" template.

So, I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing it?